# ::after pseudo element in textarea not working

Tags: css, textarea, pseudo-element

I want to mark a textarea with a warning.

I previously used the same formatting for a div, but it won't work in a textarea element.

[image]

How can I get the same for a textarea?

Code sample:

- div that works
- textarea with the exact same styles that does not work

Tested in current Chrome and firefox on Windows.

```css
textarea, div {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
textarea:after, div:after {
    content: 'Some Text';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: .6em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
  Div<br>
</div>

<textarea>
  Textarea
  Textarea
  Textarea
  Textarea
  Textarea
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hm. I suspect you can't add pseudo-elements to textareas? So I would need to add a div wrapper...

Answer (score 4):

`:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements do not work on `text-area` (and any elements that contain another element such as `img` or `input` tags).

This is because the generated content of those pseudo-element are put within the element but only the difference is, they will be placed on before/after that element's content and they act like as an element.

Comment: There are very good use cases for allow it, e.g. create a triangle bottom right of a text area.